# What is the way to point to document index/TOC/up in HTML5?

Tags: html, html4

[HTML 4 spec has rel="index" / rel="contents" / rel="up"](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-links).

[HTML 5 spec have no such elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#linkTypes).

Do they officially deprecated? Or may I just look in wrong place of HTML 5 spec?

What is the way to point to document index/TOC in HTML5 (in multi-page document)?

---

HTML 5 still have `rel="prev"` / `rel="next"` and naturally I expected for a way to express going up like in usual document navigation:

```
<Prev  |  Up  |  Next>
```

Comment: Yes, they have been officially dropped: https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=7475

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Jordan for link that described reasons for rejection of `top`/`index`/`up` from HTML 5 spec.

A few more links:

- [original issue](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=7475)
- [rel usage till 2009](http://alexandre.alapetite.fr/divers/vrac/20091115_HTML_link_rel.html)
- [why rejected](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2010Nov/0042.html)
- [commit to Git](https://github.com/whatwg/html/commit/16485bf232227f99628894f182e48bbb0634eb1d)

So there is no machine readable possibility to go one level up (especially with previous HTML 4 `rel="up"`), despite presence of semantic meaning for navigating `up` in breadcrumb, hierarchical documentation and possible forums/boards.